# How do I properly size a plot on Lollipop using AndroidPlot?

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I'm using AndroidPlot to graph data on an app I'm making.
We recently upgraded from ICS to LOLLIPOP and noticed that the graphs are sized improperly.

ICS (Appearing correctly):
[image: ICS AnroidPlot]

LOLLIPOP (Appearing incorrectly):
[image: LOLLIPOP AndroidPlot]

I'm using the exact same code for both of the above screenshots:

```
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/plot_temperatures"
        androidplot.renderMode="use_background_thread"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/spliceGreen"/>
```

How do I properly resize this plot on Lollipop?

Comment: It turns out this is caused by us changing the screen density with the following command "adb shell wm density 133"... setting the density back to 160 resolves this issue. 

Even with both ICS and LOLLIPOP on density 133 the issue only occurs on LOLLIPOP.

Answer (score 0):

Given your final comment, sounds like this would only be a bug in dev environments.  It's almost certainly due to Androidplot not receiving a notification the screen has changed via the normal mechanisms.  One thing you can try is invoking `PixelUtils.init(Context)`  followed by `Plot.redraw()` after such a resize.